# msal-browser 2.0, PC platform and logging in/token acquisition

Tags: office-addins, azure-ad-msal

I read through the docs and it seems to suggest that we need to run msal login via an async dialog because for office on the web, the taskpane starting point is not the topmost window.

However, on the PC platformtype, I think the taskpane is toplevel.

Does that mean that on the PC platform, I should be able to run a redirect dialog without issues directly in the taskpane itself?

I'm trying to use msal-browser (msal 2.0) but I keep getting the taskpane popping up a whole new browser tab outside the outlook desktop app and it breaks the login process. I'm not sure I'm doing it right though.

Does anyone have an example of running a redirect login process inside the taskpane itself for the PC platformtype using msal 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I did get this to work Ok. The new msal-browser 2.0 works fine and is probably more predictable than the 1.x series.